# How to ensure that only authorized users can run my WPF application?

Tags: wpf, deployment, registration

Our boss recently decided that the WPF application I'm working on should no longer be free and require that users pay for the product. This means that I'll have to manage a list of authorized users and ensure that only those who have paid can run the application.

What is this functionality called in general, so I can look it up and read up on my various options? Are there any tools in the .net framework to manage this?

Comment: Something to get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/398130/Software-Copy-Protection-for-Net-Applications-a-Tu

Comment: Easy way is to let users log in. If it's possible you should do that. Simple authorization where you check that concrete user provided valid password and has permission to access your application? Of course this is not possible when your application does not require internet access.